# System variables wso2

Tags: database, properties, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a list of a not allowed staff on a property (sequence) and want to generelize it to avoid deploying service once I have to update it , any suggestion please?

```
<log level="custom"> <property name="LIST NOT ALLOWED" expression="$ctx:except"/></log>     
<property name="except" value="PENTEST,None,Monitoring,Bidon" type="STRING"/>
```

Regards,
Souki

Answer (score 0):

You can read from environment variables as shown below.

```
<property expression="get-property('env','JAVA_HOME')" name="java" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Comment: Hi @ycr,

Unfortunately above mentioned way is not working for me(null as value i am getting), via script mediator it prints environment variable value. Version: WSO2 EI 6.4.0

Answer (score 0):

We can use `WSO2 Script mediator` to read system environment variable in WSO2 ESB/EI

```
    <script language="js"><![CDATA[mc.setProperty("envDatabaseURL", java.lang.System.getenv("ENV_DATABASE_URL"));
        ]]></script>
<log level="custom">
 <property expression="$ctx:envDatabaseURL" name="EnvDatabaseURL: "/>
</log>
```

For more info, please refer this [blog](http://amalkas.blogspot.com/2017/08/using-environment-variables-in-wso2.html)